# First order differential equation solution check.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have an equation:

$\frac{dy}{y}=(0.0001x^2+0.005x)dx$

$y=ce^{(0.00003x+0.0025)x^2}$

Now I try to substitute $y$ in the euqation and I am getting

$(\frac{1}{ce^{(0.00003x+0.0025)x^2}})'=0.0001x^2+0.005x$

$(\frac{1}{ce^{(0.00003x+0.0025)x^2}})'=(\frac{1}{c}e^{(-0.00003x-0.0025)x^2})'=(\frac{1}{c}e^{(-0.00003x-0.0025)x^2})(-0.0001x^2-0.005x)$

But

$(\frac{1}{c}e^{(-0.00003x-0.0025)x^2})(-0.0001x^2-0.005x) \neq 0.0001x^2+0.005x$

What am I missing here while checking the solution?

Comment: Are you sure your first equation is $$\frac{dy}{y}=(0.0001x^2+0.005x)dx$$ and not $$\frac{dy}{y}=(0.00009x^2+0.005x)dx$$

Comment: @paulplusx, yes, I am sure. It is just that I rounded carelessly.

Comment: Check my answer now. Also, edit your question and use the original equation not the rounded one. Never round-off coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation is of the form:

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} = (ax^2+bx)\mathrm{d}x $$

where $a=0.0001$ and $b=0.005$. Integrating both sides gives:

$$ \int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} = \int(ax^2+bx)\mathrm{d}x $$

The solution is

$$ \ln y = \frac{a}{3}x^3+\frac{b}{2}x^2+c$$

Therefore, in terms of $y$:

$$ y = C\mathrm{e}^{(\frac{a}{3}x+\frac{b}{2})x^2}, \label{eq1} \tag{1}$$

where $C=\mathrm{e}^c$. We can test the solution in the following way:

$$\begin{align} 
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left [ C\mathrm{e}^{(\frac{a}{3}x+\frac{b}{2})x^2} \right]\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left [ \frac{a}{3}x^3+\frac{b}{2}x^2 \right]C\mathrm{e}^{(\frac{a}{3}x+\frac{b}{2})x^2} \\
&=\left ( ax^2+bx^2 \right)C\mathrm{e}^{(\frac{a}{3}x+\frac{b}{2})x^2} 
\end{align}.$$ 
Using $\eqref{eq1}$:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} =\left ( ax^2+bx^2 \right)y 
$$

Therefore: 
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} =\left ( ax^2+bx^2 \right) \mathrm{d}x
$$

Regarding the numeric values: $a=0.0001=\frac{1}{10000}$, then $\frac{a}{3}=\frac{1}{30000}\neq 0.00003$. On the other hand, 
$$ 
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} \neq \frac{1}{y'}
$$
The right way to view the equation is the following: The differential of a function $y(x)$ is given by
$$
\mathrm{d}y=y'(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
Divide each side of the equation by $y(x)$

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\frac{y'(x)}{y}\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Then $\frac{y'(x)}{y}$ should give you $0.0001x^2+0.005x$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use that
$$
\frac{y'}{y}=(\ln|y|)'
$$
which in your case gives
$$
(\ln|ce^{(0.00003x+0.0025)x^2}|)'=(\ln|c|+0.00003x^3+0.0025x^2)'=0.00009x^2+0.005x.
$$
which is the right side of your DE within the considered accuracy.

---

Conversely, $$\left(\frac1y\right)'=-\frac{y'}{y^2}$$ which is not the expression in the original DE.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the coefficients should not be rounded-off.

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=(0.00009x^2+0.005x)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\implies \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y\mathrm{d}x}=(0.00009x^2+0.005x)$$

$$\implies \frac{y'}{y}=(0.00009x^2+0.005x)$$

Now substitute $y$ and $y'$.

Note that:

$$y'=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=ce^{(0.00003x+0.0025)x^2}\cdot  (0.00009x^2+0.005x)$$